# Codename one uwp sumbission fail

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to submit an app to the windows store, but submission failed with the following error:

```
Invalid package publisher name: CN=Steve (expected: CN= ... )
```

, which make me realized that the `AppxBundleManifest` generated from server contains this line

```
<Identity Name="42415WefeelPharm.HttpRequestor" Publisher="CN=Steve" Version="1.0.1.0"/>
```

I've confirmed that the correct package publisher id is used to generate the certificate.  Please advice on how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

The setting UI for Windows 
[image]

Edit edit:

I used Windows 10, jdk1.8.0_131, Eclipse 4.7 for the build...

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Codename One Settings UI for the Windows signing section?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the required screenshot

Comment: Try moving the PFX file to your directory and using a relative path

Comment: I've tried "/Users/Roy/_projectfolder_/Keychain.pfx", "/Keychain.pfx", "/Users/Roy/Keychain.pfx", but none worked. The browse function always point to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\Keychain.pfx" (which also have a copy of the .pfx).  Could you advice on the next step? Thank you.

Comment: Copy the keychain file to the local directory and use Keychain.pfx as the name. Make sure that you used our UI to generate the certificate

Comment: It turns out that using Netbeans to build the project instead of Eclipse solves all problem, without trying to move the Keychain.pfx to local directory... Apparently Eclipse plugin cannot load the file regardless of the use of absolute / relative location

Comment: This sounds like this issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2082 do you have the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: The eclipse plugin level is 3.7, probably the latest one

Comment: Looking at the issue it seems there should be more logging. I've reopened that can you please look at the eclipse logs and add them as a comment to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your account settings -> https://dev.windows.com/en-us/Account/Management

In the page you will see your "Windows publisher ID" copy the value "CN=xXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX60"

Go to VS, open the Package.appxmanifest, go to the line:

Change "CN=Steve" to the value you copied, "CN=xXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX60", and that's it.  Compile it and try again

Comment: Unfortunately tho I'm not using VS to compile the project so it's not applicable to my case